# Cut and copy-paste given positions of the text

Tags: regex, perl, text, sed, awk

My dummy text file (one continuous line) looks like this:

```
AAChvhkfiAFAjjfkqAPPMB
```

I want to:

1. Delete part of the text (specific range);
2. Copy-Paste (specific range of characters) within the file.

How I am doing this:

To cut part of the text at wanted positions (from 5 to 7 characters & from 10 to 14 characters) I use `cut`

```
echo 'AAChvhkfiAFAjjfkqAPPMB' | cut --complement -c 5-7,10-14  
AAChfifkqAPPMB
```

But I really don't know how to copy-paste text. For example: to copy text from 15 to 18 characters and paste it after character 1 (also using previous cut command). To get the final result like this:

```
fkqAAAChfifkqAPPMB
```

So I do have to questions:

1. How to read text (from .. to) given range using perl, awk or sed & paste this text at specific position.
2. How to combine this text pasting with the previous cut command as after cutting text will move to the left side, hence wrong text will be copied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
$ echo AAChvhkfiAFAjjfkqAPPMB | awk '{ print(substr($1, 0, 14) substr($1, 18) substr($1, 15, 3)) }'
AAChvhkfiAFAjjAPPMBfkq
```

Answer (score 1):

In [perl](/questions/tagged/perl), you can use *array slice*, by splitting the *string* in a *array* :

```
my $string = "AAChvhkfiAFAjjfkqAPPMB1";
my @arr = split //, $string;
```

and *slicing* (print element 5 to 7 and 10 to 14):

```
 print @array[5..7,10..14];
```

you can use [splice()](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/splice.html) too to re-arrange the array.

perldoc said :

> Removes the elements designated by OFFSET and LENGTH from an array, and replaces them with the elements of LIST, if any.

See http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices

Answer (score 1):

In Perl I think substr would be a good candidate, try eg.

```
$a = '1234567890';
#from pos 2, replace 3 chars with nothing, return the 3 chars
$b=substr($a,2,3,''); 
print "$a\t$b\n"; #1267890    345
#in posistion 0 (first), replace 0 characters (ie pure insert)
#with the content of $b
substr($a,0,0,$b);
print "$a\t$b\n"; #3451267890    345
```

See http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/substr.html for more details.
splice() may be a candidate as well.

Answer (score 1):

quite straightforward with awk:

```
kent$  echo "AAChvhkfiAFAjjfkqAPPMB"|awk  '
{for(i=5;i<=7;i++)$i="";
 for(i=10;i<=14;i++)$i="";
 for(i=15;i<=18;i++)t=sprintf("%s%s",t,$i);
 $0=t""$0}1' OFS="" FS=""
fkqAAAChfifkqAPPMB
```

**edit**

to reverse the part of text, you just need to swap `t` and `$i`:

```
kent$  echo "AAChvhkfiAFAjjfkqAPPMB"|awk  '
{for(i=5;i<=7;i++)$i="";
 for(i=10;i<=14;i++)$i="";
 for(i=15;i<=18;i++)t=sprintf("%s%s",$i,t);
 $0=t""$0}1' OFS="" FS=""
AqkfAAChfifkqAPPMB
```

Comment: What does `1` mean in here `$0=t""$0}1'`?  

Also I just wanted to make it clear: `$0=t""$0` - combines to sequences & prints them out (print t & then print $0). But what if i want to print `t` within `$0`? How to print `t` at specific position within `$0` string?

Comment: Joachim Pileborg's answer bellow uses `substr()` - I can imagine using this to divide final `$0` and to print in preferred order, but their should be simpler way of doing this.

Comment: `1` outside the `{...}` block means `print $0` if you want to print t at e.g. after 3rd letter, you could `$3=$3""t` or `$3=sprintf('%s%s',$3,t)`

Comment: I really liked this solution, but the problem is this thing: `awk: program limit exceeded: maximum number of fields size=32767` - had to use Joachim Pileborg solution (no maximum fields error)